# Answer count in /questions differs from count on question page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-answers, 10k-tools

I occasionally notice that a posts answer count is different on /questions as it is inside the actual post, and until now I just ignored it assuming that it was either something in cache, a deleted/ added post since I last looked, etc.

But I finally found an example of one that I believe the count to truly be wrong on: [How to get the title for a UIButton when it is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199256/how-to-get-the-title-for-a-uibutton-when-it-is-pressed)

Here's a screenshot of /questions
[image]

And here's on from inside the post. Mind you depending on your rep, you may only see that there are 2 answers inside the post because 2 others were deleted by owner.

[image]

Anyway, on to my proof! I first noticed this post when it contained four answers and none of them had been deleted. As it seemed that the current answers solved the problem I exited the post, only to see /questions refresh and show that the post now contained 3 answers.

Intrigued I reentered the post curious to see who deleted their post, and found as expected that the answer count was still 4. Left the post again and the same thing happened!

I'm not arguing that the posts internal answer count shouldn't reflect deleted posts because I like the feature. But, is there a reason that a posts answer count in /questions doesn't reflect deleted posts as well?

Comment: Maybe because of web and browser cache?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri It isn't really my area of expertise, but I don't think so. The vote count on /question did update, but only to reflect the number of non deleted answers in the post and as a 10k+ user I'm wondering why this number doesn't represent the number of answers that I'm allowed to see.

Comment: As noted in the answer below...as a 10k user you'll see a mismatch here, by design when there are deleted answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main page only tells you how many **non-deleted** answers there are.

On your question in question, there are **2** deleted answers.